# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n r^{\frac1r}$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_{r=1}^n r^{\frac1r}$?

---

I've tried finding it, and I know that without the $\frac1n$ factor, the sequence has the limit $n$. What about the series? Will it be 1, then? How to show?

Comment: It cannot have the limit $n$ since $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Apply the theorem of Cesaro-Stolz to reduce this to the limit of $n^{1/n}$, which is 1.

Comment: @LutzL you should post this as hint-like answer

Comment: @JPi, I didn't mean that. I've edited the question correctly.

Comment: @LutzL, it actually reduces to the limit of $\frac{n^{\frac1n}}{n}$. Isn't it so? Now if we use product of limits, then it is 0.

Comment: No, one has to represent the denominator also as a partial sum of n terms, and since $n-(n-1)=1$ ...

Answer (score 2):

The theorem of Cesaro-Stolz states that if $b_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=\infty$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{b_1+...+b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
if the limit to the right exists. The left side may converge even if the right side does not.

This can be applied here fruitfully.